# 500 Internal Server Error on Ajax request. Not sure the origin of the problem

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error and I can't figure out the origin of the problem. This request is supposed to delete a comment with a certain id from the database. The id is passed using a hidden input. Here's my code:

My form:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    <button class='submit-btn delete-comment' type='submit' name='commentDelete'>X</button>
</form>

<script>
    var urlDeleteComment = '{{ route('deleteComment') }}';
</script>
```

My route:

```
Route::delete('/comment', 'CommentsController@deleteComment')->name('deleteComment');
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('.delete-comment').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var commentId = $("input[name=comment_id]").val();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlDeleteComment,
        data: {
            commentId: commentId,
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function(response) {

    })
});
```

My PHP:

```
public function deleteComment(Request $request){
    $commentId = $request['commentId'];
    $comment = Comment::find($commentId);
    $comment->delete();
}
```

After I use console.log(commentId) in the JavaScript, I get the id of the number so it seems that I am successfully getting it. Sadly I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the 500 Internal Server Error. I just know that it is a server side error but I can't figure out what is it.

I checked the logs and saw this error:

```
[2018-12-20 22:12:23] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments` (`user_id`, `image_id`, `comment`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , 2018-12-20 22:12:23, 2018-12-20 22:12:23)) 
{"userId":1,"email":"bojidar_s_k@abv.bg","exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments`
(`user_id`, `image_id`, `comment`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , 2018-12-20 22:12:23, 2018-12-20 22:12:23)) at C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\Art\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664,
PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null at C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\Art\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:458)
[stacktrace]
```

Now the weird thing is that this is not even part of the deleteComment() function but rather than part of a previous function called postComment(). Here is the full PHP code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use App\Image;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function postComment(Request $request){
        $userId = $request['userId'];
        $imageId = $request['imageId'];
        $commentText = $request['comment'];
        $image = Image::with('user')->find($imageId);

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->user_id = $userId;
        $comment->image_id = $imageId;
        $comment->comment = $commentText;
        $comment->save();

        $image->updateComments();

        return response()->json(['comment'=>$comment, 'image'=>$image]);
    }

    public function deleteComment(Request $request){
        $commentId = $request['commentId'];
        $comment = Comment::find($commentId);
        $comment->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `$request['commentId'];` to `$request->get('commentId');` You'll need to spoof the method in your ajax call too: `'_method' : 'DELETE'`

Comment: Still receiving the same error.

Comment: Without any error information its going to be difficult to troubleshoot. Provide some error information from your `laravel.log` file.

Comment: I checked the laravel.log and it's just a single line of unreadable code so I'm not even sure what to post.

Comment: Can you tell me what did you mean by "You'll need to spoof the method in your ajax call too: '_method' : 'DELETE'"?

Comment: Did you add CSRF token? [X-CSRF-TOKEN docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: Yes {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: That's not enough if you are doing ajax call. In the link that I provided, with the jQuery you need the part `$.ajaxSetup(...`

Comment: Just follow the 2 steps: add `<meta...` on you page and `$.ajaxSetup(...`

Comment: I've checked the logs and found an error that might be related to my issue, however, I'm not even sure why am I getting it since the error seems to be part of a previous function which works until I add the code for the deleteComment function.

Comment: You should clear your **laravel.log** file, try to delete comment with ajax again and check the log file after. Just to make sure that your error message is related.

Comment: I did that and that was the first fresh error that appeared. The timestamp also proves it. I'm perplexed why is this error even appearing. The functionality to post a comment works until I add the deleteComment() function below it. Then it stops and both functions stop working.

Comment: I do have a route that is the exact as the one you've posted. Do I add the _method: 'delete' to the data object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your delete endpoint your ajax call should look like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlDeleteComment,
    data: {
        commentId: commentId,
        _method: 'DELETE',
        _token: token
    }
}).done(function(response) {

})
```

Comment: Thanks @KirkBeard. I noticed the comments piling up.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code

```
<form method='POST' id='delete_comment'>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
    @csrf
    <div id="status" style="display: none;"></div>
    <button class='submit-btn delete-comment' type='submit' name='commentDelete'>X</button>
</form>
```

Route:

```
// POST 
Route::post('/comment/delete', 'CommentsController@deleteComment')->name('deleteComment');
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#delete_comment').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // ADD WAIT CSS IF YOU WANT HERE :) 
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('deleteComment') }}",
   method:"POST",
   data: new FormData(this),
   // DATA RETURN JSON
   dataType:'JSON',
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    // REMOVE YOUR WAIT CSS BEFORE SHOW YOUR SUCCESS MSG

    // SHOW SUCCESS OR WARNING MSG
    jQuery('#status').toggle('show');
    $('#status').addClass(data.status);
    $('#status').innerHTML = data.msg;
   },
   error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
   }
   });
 });

});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
protected function deleteComment(Request $request){
    // NOT GIVE ANY ONE TO DELETE YOUR COMMNET 
    $comment = Comment::find($request->comment_id);
    // CHECK IF IS COMMNET IN DATABASE :) 
    if ($comment) {
        $comment->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'success', 
            'status' => 'alert alert-success'
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'msg' => 'error, not found', 
        'status' => 'alert alert-danger'
    ]);
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you changed in this to fix the problem?

Comment: By using `Route::post`, And some changes